# How to clone (copy) an order in magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, magento2.3

I need to create a new order starting for an existing one (but change some options) programatically (I'll create an API to trigger the new order creation passing the starting order id).

Could anyone point me in the right direction to obtain that?

Thank You

Comment: Can you please describe what you are looking for?

Comment: The need is to clone an existing order by triggering an API. Anyway I found  the way looking in code that manages reorder action from admin (Magento\Sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create)